# Prove/Disprove: $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous on $[-1,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $(f_n)$ be the sequence of functions defined on $[-1,1]$ by:
>
> $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0, &\text{if $-1 \le x \le -1/n$} \\
> (1 + nx)/2, &\text{if $-1/n \le x \le 1/n$} \\
> 1, &\text{if $1/n \le x \le 1$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove/Disprove: $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous on $[-1,1]$.

This is actually a part of a question which asks to prove that $(f_n)$ is bounded, pointwise convergent, not uniformly convergent, and that $f_n$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ for each $n$.

I have done all of these, but this one I do not know how to approach it.

**Attempt:**

I think that it won't be equicontinuous, and I thought about proving disequicontinuity at $0$ because it is the point of "problems" in this question.

As a reminder, $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous at $x_0$ if:

$$\forall \ \epsilon > 0, \ \exists \delta > 0, \ \forall \ x, |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f_n(x) - f_n(x_0)| < \epsilon, \forall \ n \in \mathbb N$$

Where $\mathbb N:= \{1, 2, \ldots\}$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$(f_n)$ is not equicontinuous at $0$ as for all $n \ge 1$
$$\vert f_n(1/n) - f_n(0) \vert =1/2$$

Jean-Pierre - http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/